# radius of two same circles in one 4*7 rectangle？

Tags: geometry

There is a rectangle（4*7） with two same circles inside.The circles are not overlapping.
How long is the radius of the circle when the circle is the biggest？

I set the radius=x.

> 2x<=4
> 4x<=7

So I can calculate

> x<=7/4=1.75

Is it right?

Comment: Welcome to [math.se] SE. Take a [tour]. You'll find that simple "Here's the statement of my question, solve it for me" posts will be poorly received. What is better is for you to add context (with an [edit]): What you understand about the problem, what you've tried so far, *etc.*; something both to show you are part of the learning experience and to help us guide you to the appropriate help. You can consult [this link](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/q/9959) for further guidance.

Comment: You are only considering the case where the segment joining the centers is parallel to the side of length 7, but the problem does not exclude a priori the possibility that said segment is oblique.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Hint: common sense dictates, that the circles are biggest, if one is aligned at one corner at the rectangle, and the other is at the opposite. Now if we start with radius 0 and both centers at the corners and keep incrementing the radius till their contours touch, then the centers move on two parallel lines starting at the corners and the distance must be the same at each point from the adjacent sides of the rectangle. Also common sense dictates that as the entire drawing is symmetric along the adjacent sides, then the point of touch is at the middle of the rectangle, i.e. at the intersection of the two lines that are bisectors of the opposite sides.

Comment: Thanks for the hint!I drawed like that and found the right solution maybe.
4r²=(7-2r)²+（4-2r)²    
r~=1.758